# What PM certifications are worthwhile acquiring?

Tags: certification

I currently have two under my belt, I am Scrum Master certified, and Prince 2. I have found that obtaining Prince 2 has been pointless, I never use it whereas the Scrum master certification was well worth the money, since I am using it everyday.

I am looking towards obtaining more certifications, for heavily certified PMs on here, which ones do you recommend for digital projects? I am having a look at PMP right now but not sure if it is worth the money. Also, has being heavily certified impacted your employment prospects positively.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer to your question but I can advise you how to find the answer.  Look at the advertisements for the jobs to which you are applying and see what certificates they "prefer" or "require."  As well, if you get rejected, ask why and if they report a missing certificate as the or one of the causes, there's your answer.

Thoughts on PMP: This certificate is used as a hiring filter in the space in which I work.  Though public sector--in which they are not supposed to use a commercial certificate as a filter--it is often a requirement or preferred.  As such, I value it in order to sell.

As a certificate with hiring validity, I do not value it.  Anecdotally, I see no difference in performance between those who have it and those who do not.  Additionally, there have been studies, both on the PMP itself (Booz) and certificates as a predictor (Hunter & Hunter), that have shown very poor predictive validity, which matches my observations.

That said, if you don't have to pay for it. why not get it?  If you do have to pay for it, then see who is asking for it so you can try to determine if you're going to have a decent return on your outlay to get it.

Comment: Ok - seems in that case that I have all the relevant certifications already.

Comment: What are your thoughts about PMP?

Comment: Do you work in the digital space? Says in your profile that you work on projects in the healthcare/public sector. My only concern about PMP is that it might end up being like Prince 2, used in the public sector but irrelevant for digital where projects are run in an agile way. I ended up forking out quite a bit of cash for my Prince 2 certification. Saying that would love to work for a blue chip like you are!

Comment: I do not but we have practices in my firm that do.  PMP still seems to be the most asked for certificate but I suspect PMI-ACP might grow in popularity.  Perhaps you should consider that instead of the PMP if you're forced to choose only one.  If able, do both.  In the commercial, private sector space, I have no idea if any customer is asking for any type of certificate.

Answer (score 0):

More important than getting the certification is the experience that brings to you when you are preparing yourself for that challenge. So it's always good to have it; and off course people would listen more to you when they know your qualifications.

Comment: The OP wasn't really asking if certifications in general are useful, but instead asking which ones are the most useful.

Comment: Yeah, I see. But I like to give my opinion. :-) There is no most useful or less useful, it all depends on what exactly he is working on. Prince is famous in Europe and used on all government bodies, on the other hand, you see the PMI being used a lot in the USA.

Comment: I work in digital, so wondering which ones are the best ones to obtain for this field.

Answer (score 0):

PMP is helpful in the sense that it ensures a common lingo: that becomes important when you have a large organization with many project managers